# Android Button back - > home

Tags: android, session, button, android-button, whatsapp

I have a question about the back button.

When I launch to the application, and then press the button to go back, (back to the MainActivity), I need a similar action that makes WhatsApp.

My Example:
MainAcitivy -> listusers -> anothers 
users (back) -> MainActivity

Example of WhatsApp 
MainAcitivy -> listusers-> anothers 
users (back) -> home, or current site

I tried SharedPreferences, but it always goes to ... I do not understand MainActivity 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Any ideas?

Comment: this is about the back button navigation http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to override the [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method of Activity. Override this method, and assign it any function you want.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: correct, but if I replace onBackPressed (), eventually I want to implement fragments, that i will be a big problem, I prefer my button go to home how whatssap

Comment: If you override the onBackPressed() on activities, it will function in  its fragments, or you can add .addToBackStack(null) to make the fragments go back normally.

Comment: Okey I will implement.addToBackStack(null), in Intent I need finish() for close app not ? I need : MainAcitivy -> listusers -> anothers users (back) -> MainActivity(not)  Home(yes)

Comment: If you want to close an app, use the finish() method, yes.

Comment: not work, not close my MainAcitivty... I tried "http://androidexample.com/Android_Session_Management_Using_SharedPreferences_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=127&aaid=147"   and works correctly, something like here code, u can download and try and press back and u see, is awesome!!

Comment: U can try this example? I need same operation, but with sharepreferences

Comment: What do you need it to do with SharedPreferences?

Comment: I need do : "login - > save datas(shprf), and when press back, not return MainActivity", return home, detect session, exactly whatssap

Comment: I'm not understanding you. You want to go to the homepage after you click on the back button?

Comment: how you might not understand me? whatssap you have? happens when you hit the back arrow back? do not think you come back again whenever loggin back.

Comment: So you login to the app, save the data, then press back, and you return to WhatsApp because you're logged in?

Comment: Alguien puede decirme cómo puedo hacer la misma función que tiene whatssap ? 
cuando estas dentro que te sale la lista desplegable de whatssap, cuando le das al botón de volver hacia atrás, te dirige al home, no vuelves hacer un loggin otra vez, para eso existe el desconectarse, que entonces sí vuelves al Main.

Comment: Solved :

MainActivity intent + finish + preferences -- > next Activity get preferences